# Por que alguns caracteres não funcionam em tags?

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tags

Por que razão alguns caracteres não funcionam nas tags? Por exemplo, aqui no meta temos [traducão](/questions/tagged/traduc%c3%a3o) mas não [tradução](/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o) - o `ã` funciona bem mas o `ç` não.

Que outros caracteres são afetados por isto, e pode ser corrigido?

Traduzido de:

> (My apologies that this is in English, but: I know exactly zero Portuguese, and a mechanical translation is usually unintelligible)
>
> Why is it that some characters don't work in tags? for example, here on meta we have [traducão](/questions/tagged/traduc%c3%a3o) but not [tradução](/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o) - the `ã` is fine but the `ç` is not. What other characters are affected by this, and can it be fixed?

Comment: No problem, Marc. We'll translate for you when it needed.

Comment: @Marc, could you help in this CSS problem: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/78/texto-cortado-na-tela-de-analise-de-edicoes-sugeridas - the `.question-summary` div is too short and the content is not shown.

Answer (score 12):

Isto é basicamente devido a um "hack" / atalho / remendo de código que tivémos que fazer hà muitos anos, quando estavamos a utilizar o "text search" do servidor SQL para gerir as tags. Por razões técnicas, a maneira como implementámos isto foi usando caracteres especiais para representar valores que de outra maneira não apareceriam nas buscas (`+`, `.`, `-`, etc), o que occorre frequentemente em tags de programação. Apesar de termos deixado de usar este método há bastante tempo, este código ainda estava presente e só agora com a internacionalização das tags o problema se mostrou.

Os valores que estavam bloqueados eram:

```
à é ñ ç ö û
```

Apesar de o numero de caracteres não ser grande foi o suficiente para gerar problemas aqui no br.stackoverflow.com.

Finalmente revimos este código e retirou-se os rastos (*rastros*) deste "hack". As boas notícias são: a partir de agora já deve ser possível usar estes 6 caracteres.

Por enquanto isto está activo somente no meta.br.stackoverflow.com - para limitar o impacto enquanto fazemos validações das mudanças. Estas mudanças serão também implementadas br.stackoverflow.com assim que tivermos a certeza que elas não danificam o site.

Traduzido de:

> This basically relates to a "hack" that we made many years ago, when we were using SQL server full text search to handle many tag features. Due to technical reasons, the way we implemented this was by using some special characters to represent values that otherwise would not be searchable - `+`, `.`, `-` etc - which occur commonly in programming tags. Even though we had long since ceased using full text search for this, when it came time to add international tag support, these special tokens still remained in the code. The values that were blocked were:
>
> à é ñ ç ö û
>
> Not a large number, but enough to be problematic on br.stackoverflow.com.
>
> We have now taken the time to revisit this code, removing the last traces of this old "hack". The good news is that you should now be able to use these last 6 characters.
>
> At the current time this is enabled **only** on meta.br.stackoverflow.com - to limit impact while we validate the changes. These changes will be deployed to br.stackoverflow.com as soon as we're sure that we won't damage the site in any way.

Comment: Obrigado! (Google translate should get this one right :)). I'm on the go right now, but I can translate this q & a in about two hours, if nobody's done that yet by then.

Comment: @bfavaretto De nada. Nós queríamos fazer isso por muito tempo, este foi o último empurrão que precisávamos.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu poderia traduzir, mas não posso editar.

Comment: Alguém traduzindo?

Comment: @utluiz, sim. Mas pode corrigir se achar algum erro.

Comment: @MarcGravell, thanks for info!

Comment: @MarcGravell Main site is ok too? There is another related bug. See bottom of image: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/442/bug-na-acentuacao-fora-das-tags

Comment: @bigown yes, it is enabled on the main site - thanks for the heads-up on the link

Comment: What's the status of é and friends in tags now? [Database inconsistencies after tag-merge operations involving non-ASCII characters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224158/database-inconsistencies-after-tag-merge-operations-involving-non-ascii-characte)

Comment: @Gilles emailing that to myself to look at tomorrow